# SSL and Load Balancing

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

What affect does SSL have on the way load balancing works? I know that you need to use sticky sessions if you have chosen to not store you session info in the DB or Out of Process but how does that effect SSL?

Comment: found this interesting link http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/StickySessions

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just to clarify, the SSL/TLS sessions have nothing to do with the HTTP sessions. (Some implementations may use the SSL/TLS session ID as a basis for maintaining HTTP sessions, but this is a bad design, as SSL/TLS may change sessions completely independently what HTTP is doing).

In terms of load balancing, you get a couple of options:

- Use a load-balancer that is your SSL/TLS endpoint. In this case, the load-balancing will be done at the HTTP level: the client connects to the load-balancer and the load-balancer unwraps the SSL/TLS connection to pass on the HTTP content (then in clear) to its workers.
- Use a load-balancer at the TCP/IP level, which redirects entire the TCP connection directly to a worker node. In this case, each worker node would have to have the certificate and private key (which isn't necessarily a problem if they're administered consistently). Using this technique, the load balancer doesn't do any HTTP processing at all (since it doesn't look within the SSL/TLS connection): on the one hand this reduces the processing done by the load-balancer itself, on the other hand it would prevent you from dispatching to a particular worker node based on the URL structure for example. Both methods have their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Good answer! A disadvantage of the second method that you might want to mention is that the balancer, since it cannot see the HTTP request inside of all of that SSL, cannot add a header stating the real client IP; so to the web server, it will look as though all requests come from a single web client: the IP address of the load balancer itself.

Comment: @Brandon Craig Rhodes, you might be able to get the load-balancer send the packet as if it came from the initial client, like reverse NATs can do.

Comment: — true, but only in the case where I modify all of the servers to use the load balancer as their TCP gateway so that all of those packets going back out toward arbitrary client IPs pass back through the balancer. And so far as I know, that is only possible if I am actually running the machines on the same LAN so that they have Ethernet-level access to each other's network interfaces? (And therefore not possible with arbitrary hosts from a cloud server provider?)

Comment: How do I make amazon load balancer to act as the second one?

Comment: Good answer, but I would add one more disadvantage of TCP/IP level load balancing for a web site:  the load balancer would not be able to use cookie based HTTP session affinity, since the cookies would be part of the encrypted data not visible to the load balancer.  This means that different web servers would sometimes be getting HTTP requests for the same HTTP session, which has significant ramifications for the web server code.