# SSL and Load Balancing

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSL and Load Balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871886/ssl-and-load-balancing)

We're thinking about using a software based load balancer for our website. However some apis on our website are protected by SSL. My question is: say our website was netflix.com, we have 2 webservers 1 and 2. So if netflix.com domain pointed to the load balancer server, will SSL still work when the load balancer connects to websever 1 or 2, or am I understanding something wrong?

Thanks,
Faisal Abid

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871886/ssl-and-load-balancing/3881084#3881084