# How can I access a TLS Session ID within an ASP.NET session? (To avoid BEAST cookie theft)

Tags: asp.net, security, cookies, ssl, isapi

[This post](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg08129.html) refers to a way to avoid cookie theft by using a TLS Session ID as an alternative.

How would I access the TLS Session ID within ASP.NET?

Comment: You might want to review the follow-ups to the post.  There are some very real challenges/disadvantages to the proposed solution which, IMHO, make it untenable.

Comment: I'm curious about the approach of using the TLS Session ID as a key (or even 2nd validation) of session state, possibly removing the need for cookies in some cases.  With regard to Proxies, and SSL accelerated sessions, I'm thinking it is best used as as a validation token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was getting a bit long for comments and really is the answer:

Review the accepted answer, specifically the first paragraph here: [SSL and Load Balancing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871886/ssl-and-load-balancing)

What nico posted in the link you provided is just not workable except in a very narrow use case... and requires server changes.

He even lists the real problem in his "disadvantages" section.  Namely:

> TLS session IDs must be exposed up the TLS and HTTP server-side stack
>   (including any concentrators);

Until those are exposed, which I'm not convinced they ever should be, you aren't going to get access to them within .Net.  Bruno pointed out (in the question I linked to) the exact same situation.  If you have a load balancer, NAT or some other appliance like an SSL concentrator then this information will never even reach your web server...

Comment: In regard to the link: That's OK if the session ID changes, the server will know what it is and perhaps (hopefully) notify me of the change. I just want to explore the idea of using TLS SessionID as a two-factor validation of accessing session data

Comment: In regard to disadvantages: My interpretation is that there are 2 session IDs between the client and the proxy, and another between the proxy and the server.  Yes, it is less effective in that scenario, but how broad is the usage of SSL proxies/accelerators between the client and my server?