# ssl certificate through amazon elastic load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, load

I have a EC2 instance that act as a web server, it hosts various sites and some of them have ssl certificates, lets say one of them is secure.abc.com and has certificate for https://secure.abc.com

After I added an elastic load balancer, assuming it's public dns 'myelb.amazon.com' and I changed the cname record in my DNS to make 'secure' to point to 'myelb.amazon.com', the certificate becomes invalid.

How do I fix this?

My second question is if I have more than one site that has ssl certificates, will a single load balancer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, there is an option to select "TCP" instead of "HTTP"/"HTTPS" which will make the ELB work at the TCP/IP level

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this issue, you need multi domain SSl certificate to protect your multiple domains includes your DNS domain name also..!

A single certificate for your domain names is the solution for your issue!

And for second question, answer is yes, if you have website with SSL certificate then your load balancer work for it, even it works for multiple host name or ip address too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_UpdatingLoadBalancerSSL.html) should help you out

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am aware that I can load my existing certificates to load balancer, and it worked. Regarding the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871886/ssl-and-load-balancing I think the ELB is trying to do the first role, but I just want it to perform the second role (not processing the https)